# Whats meaning of obj-y += something/ in linux kernel Makefile?

Tags: c, linux, makefile, linux-kernel

I understand the meaning of

```
obj-$(CONFIG_USB)       += usb.o
```

if CONFIG_USB  is y then usb.o will be compiled. So now how to understand this

```
obj-y               += something/
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Kernel Makefiles are part of the `kbuild` system, documented in various places on the web, for example http://lwn.net/Articles/21835/.  The relevant excerpt is here:

> ```
> --- 3.1 Goal definitions
> ```
>
> Goal definitions are the main part (heart) of the kbuild Makefile.
>     These lines define the files to be built, any special compilation
>     options, and any subdirectories to be entered recursively.
>
> The most simple kbuild makefile contains one line:
>
> Example:        obj-y += foo.o
>
> This tell kbuild that there is one object in that directory named
>     foo.o. foo.o will be build from foo.c or foo.S.
>
> If foo.o shall be built as a module, the variable obj-m is used.
>     Therefore the following pattern is often used:
>
> Example:        obj-$(CONFIG_FOO) += foo.o
>
> $(CONFIG_FOO) evaluates to either y (for built-in) or m (for module).
>     If CONFIG_FOO is neither y nor m, then the file will not be compiled
>     nor linked.

So `m` means module, `y` means built-in (stands for yes in the kernel config process), and $(CONFIG_FOO) pulls the right answer from the normal config process.

Comment: What will happen if there is command like this: ***obj-y += dirname/***, there is no bracket and the command inside that bracket?

Comment: See the answer from @Étienne above, and the kbuild documentation section referenced there.  It means that `make` will descend into that directory and evaluate the Makefile found there.  The `-y` part means "do it all the time, not dependent on any configuration flag".

Answer (score 13):

obj-y               += something/

This means that kbuild should go into the directory "something". Once it moves to this directory, it looks at the Makefile in "something" to decide what objects should be built.

It is analogous to saying- go to the directory "something" and execute "make"

Comment: What will happen if there is command like this: ***obj-y  += dirname/***, there is no bracket and the command inside that bracket?

Answer (score 10):

Your question seems to be why a whole directory is added as a goal, the relevant part of the KConfig documentation is:

```
--- 3.6 Descending down in directories

    A Makefile is only responsible for building objects in its own
    directory. Files in subdirectories should be taken care of by
    Makefiles in these subdirs. The build system will automatically
    invoke make recursively in subdirectories, provided you let it know of
    them.

    To do so obj-y and obj-m are used.
    ext2 lives in a separate directory, and the Makefile present in fs/
    tells kbuild to descend down using the following assignment.

    Example:
        #fs/Makefile
        obj-$(CONfIG_EXT2_FS) += ext2/

    If CONFIG_EXT2_FS is set to either 'y' (built-in) or 'm' (modular)
    the corresponding obj- variable will be set, and kbuild will descend
    down in the ext2 directory.
    Kbuild only uses this information to decide that it needs to visit
    the directory, it is the Makefile in the subdirectory that
    specifies what is modules and what is built-in.

    It is good practice to use a CONFIG_ variable when assigning directory
    names. This allows kbuild to totally skip the directory if the
    corresponding CONFIG_ option is neither 'y' nor 'm'.
```

Comment: by the way, after adding all the .o files in the obj-y variable, where does it actually compile them? I mean where in one of many Makefiles in the kernel tree?